# Compiler, assembler and IDE on Ubuntu on ARM

Tags: linux, ide, c, compiler, arm

I am new to ARM world. I have written a program involving a C function and also some assembly code. I cross compiled it on my x86 based system (Ubuntu) using `g++-arch-linux-gnu`. Now I have gotten my hands on an ARM board (Tek) with ARM 8 Cortex cores (Aarch64) with Ubuntu installed on it. I need some guidance to what software tools I should use for my development.

1. Is there a GCC compiler/assembler which I can install on my ARM system running Ubuntu? I am specially stuck finding a proper assembler.
2. I was thinking of using gdb for debugging, but does anyone have a suggestion for a good IDE (free if possible) which comes with a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

The entire GCC tool chain, *(including the compilers, assembler & GDB)*, for your target board *should* either already be installed on the system running Ubuntu but if it is not then it *almost certainly* will be available from within the package manager on the board. Try opening a terminal and typing `g++ --version` to test.

If you wish to debug from on the board or remotely from a host machine you can do so from within the [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) IDE.

All of the above is Free, Gratis & Open Source.